# Jackson, JsonProperty can rename attributes objects?

Tags: java, json, spring, maven, jackson

I'm trying to deserialize a JSON into a Java object `Members` and then add it to my database. I use Spring Maven.

I create the Java object but the attribute names of my object must be renamed to be inserted in my database. That's why I use `@JsonProperty`. It doesn't work and I think Jackson is being misused.

My java Class `Members` with attributes `cip`,`idMemberStatus`, `lastName`, `firstName`, `email`:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.*;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "members")
@JsonPropertyOrder({"cip_etudiant", "nom", "prenom"})
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"app","cote_r","departement","inscription", "profil_id", "programme","trimestre_id", "unit_id","idMemberStatus"})
public class Members {

   @Id
   @JsonAlias("cip_etudiant")
   @JsonProperty("cip")
   private String cip;

   @JsonProperty("id_member_status")
   private int idMemberStatus;

   @JsonAlias("nom")
   @JsonProperty("last_name")
   private String lastName;

   @JsonAlias("prenom")
   @JsonProperty("first_name")
   private String firstName;

   @JsonAlias("courriel")
   @JsonProperty("email")
   private String email;

   public Members() {}

   public Members(String cip, int idMemberStatus, String lastName, String firstName, String email) {
       this.cip = cip;
       this.idMemberStatus = idMemberStatus;
       this.lastName = lastName;
       this.firstName = firstName;
       this.email = email;
   }
   ... getters and setters...
}
```

For my database, fields should be named `cip`,`id_member_status`,`last_name`, `first_name` and `email`. That's what I put in `@JsonProperty`.

Here how I deserialize my Json:

```
@Bean
public CommandLineRunner runner(MembersDao repository) throws IOException{
    return (args) -> {

        InputStream data = new FileInputStream("test.json");
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        List<Members> members = mapper.readValue(data, new TypeReference<List<Members>>(){});

        Iterator<Members> iterator = members.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()){
            Members m = iterator.next();
            if (m.getEmail()==null) m.setEmail("test");
            m.setIdMemberStatus(1);
        }

        repository.saveAll(members);
    };
}
```

But as `members` has the attributes fields `cip`,`idMemberStatus`, `lastName`, `firstName`, `email`, the last line isn't working.
I don't know how I should proceed. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Also, here my Maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.7</version>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: Jackson's JsonProperty annotation allows configuring how Jackson serializes a property to JSON. It doesn't allow configuring how JPA maps a property to a database column. You need to use JPA's Column annotation to do that.

Comment: And telling us that a line "isn't working" isn't helpful at all. Don't make us guess what the problem is. Tell precisely what you expect to happen, and what happens instead, including the complete and exact error if any.